# Passing void pointer as fucntion parameter to achive new address (char, int)

Tags: c, pointers

There is data in memory and i want to read it with it's pointer. Is it allowed to modify void pointer to char, int etc by passing this pointer to function.
I mean:

```
struct DataContainer {
  char* one;
  int* two;
};

void GetDataPointer(char var, void* data_p)
{
  switch(var) {
   case 1:
     data_p = (void*)DataContainer.one;
     break;
   case 2:
     data_p = (void*)DataContainer.two;
     break;
}

void main(void)
{
  char* example;
  GetDataPointer(1, (void*)example);
}
```

In function `GetDataPointer` i can see that `data_p` obtain the same address as Datacontainer.one, but in `main()` address of `example` remains unchanged.

Comment: `void main()`....nopes, use `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: Please roll back, that's not a duplicate question.

Comment: please [edit] your question then, because as I see now, it's a duplicate.

Comment: The link to the original question is not even relevant to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
GetDataPointer(1, (char **) &example);
```

In the function declaration you'll put this:

```
char **data_p
```

And when you set the value of the pointer:

```
*data_p = something;
```

Comment: But if i want to get int pointer?

Comment: Then make a pointer to union: `union { char *charptr; int *intptr; }`